# Android: Create new screen to the existing project as first view

Tags: android

I created a new Android project through Eclipse.

I am able to run in emulator and device. I am learning Android development.

I want to have a login screen now as a first screen.

I need insert this screen(new layout) now in the existing project.

What is the procedure to do this ?

How can i insert a new view to the existing project and that should be first screen of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Manifest.xml` make your Login activity as `LAUNCHER`

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.activities.LoginScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and other activities as DEFAULT

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: I added this. Does this create new class file automatically? I don't observed this creates new login class file. And, it is giving error in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); R cannot be resolved error in the existing mainactivity class file.

Comment: No it will not...You have to add them..Right Click on your  package under `src` folder and add one `class` file for login. For xml right click on `layout` folder add android `xml` file for layout design

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/31/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-new-activity-class-with-manifest-editor/), another way through `Manifest`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add below line under `onCreate` method of launcher activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

where `activity_main` will be your login screen layout.

Comment: No. How can i create new view designed UI for a Login screen and add that screen as first view of my existing project? Do I need to right click create new layout? setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is already there in onCreate method in MainActivity.java file.